# Monotone Increasing Criteria

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$. To prove the sequence is monotone increasing, is it sufficient for me to prove that $a_{n + 1}/a_{n} > 1$ or $a_{n + 1} - a_{n} > 0$ for arbitrary $n$? I believe the answer is yes; but, one example I am looking at uses induction. Is induction necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you show $a_{n+1}-a_n>0$ for all $n$ then clearly it is monotone increasing, nothing to prove here. As for $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ you have to be more careful. Look at the sequence $a_n=-n$. Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{n}>1$ for all $n$ but the sequence is actually monotone decreasing. If you have a sequence of positive numbers though then yes, showing $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$ for all $n$ is enough, no need to use induction.